# Access inner keys in json data in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object, key

I have this following object

```
{
    "Monday": [
        {
            "morning": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "07:30"
                }
            ],
            "afternoon": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "05:00"
                }
            ],
            "evening": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:30",
                    "end_time": "07:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
        {
            "morning": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "07:30"
                }
            ],
            "afternoon": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "05:00"
                }
            ],
            "evening": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:30",
                    "end_time": "07:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
..
}
```

i want to loop through all object keys and values

```
for (var prop in this.jsonData) {
  console.log("Key:" + prop);
  console.log("Value:" + this.jsonData[prop]);
}
```

getting

> Key:Monday value : undefined

but i need to access inner object values.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @mandy8055 the above is the json structure that i got now i'm trying to access all the values, like i will check the tuesday key then within tuesday morning, afternoon and evening slots time

Comment: Can you please make sure that you share code that reproduces your issue properly? Your code currently [does not produce](https://jsfiddle.net/jwf4do7z/) the output you're mentioning (the link has been modified to remove the `this` context, as it's not clear what that is in your example code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through the inner arrays as well to access the inner object values. Basically, this can be achieved using:

- *[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)* to get an array of key-value pairs for the outer and inner objects.
- Iterating through the arrays, and
- destructuring to extract the values directly from the objects.

```
Object.entries(this.jsonData).forEach(([day, dayData]) => {
  console.log("Day:", day);
  const timePeriods = dayData[0];

  Object.entries(timePeriods).forEach(([timePeriod, slots]) => {
    console.log("  Time Period:", timePeriod);

    slots.forEach(({ start_time, end_time }, i) => {
      console.log(`    Slot ${i + 1}`);
      console.log("      Start Time:", start_time);
      console.log("      End Time:", end_time);
    });
  });
});
```

```js
const jsonData = {
  Monday: [
    {
      morning: [
        {
          start_time: "02:00",
          end_time: "07:30",
        },
      ],
      afternoon: [
        {
          start_time: "02:00",
          end_time: "05:00",
        },
      ],
      evening: [
        {
          start_time: "02:30",
          end_time: "07:00",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  Tuesday: [
    {
      morning: [
        {
          start_time: "02:00",
          end_time: "07:30",
        },
      ],
      afternoon: [
        {
          start_time: "02:00",
          end_time: "05:00",
        },
      ],
      evening: [
        {
          start_time: "02:30",
          end_time: "07:00",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

Object.entries(jsonData).forEach(([day, dayData]) => {
  console.log("Day:", day);
  const timePeriods = dayData[0];

  Object.entries(timePeriods).forEach(([timePeriod, slots]) => {
    console.log("  Time Period:", timePeriod);

    slots.forEach(({ start_time, end_time }, i) => {
      console.log(`    Slot ${i + 1}`);
      console.log("      Start Time:", start_time);
      console.log("      End Time:", end_time);
    });
  });
});
```

---

##### Edit:

You need to typecast the `slots` explicitly. Something like:

```
(slots as { start_time: string; end_time: string }[]).foreach(...)
```

*[Typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGb5Jm)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer getting this error `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'unknown'` in line slots.foreach...

Comment: yes using typescript

Comment: @user3653474 please mention it in your question. It is not mentioned there. And for the solution just typecast it.

Comment: i have mentioned

Comment: Thanks, In cases if i have blank object i get error `ERROR TypeError: slots.forEach is not a function`  where we have to put condition for blank object

Answer (score 0):

### Nested Objects Accessing

As we can see the object structure is rather complex, we need to go deep inside all the subobjects, i.e. day and then to time.

To do that, we can write a function:

```js
this.jsonData = {
    "Monday": [
        {
            "morning": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "07:30"
                }
            ],
            "afternoon": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "05:00"
                }
            ],
            "evening": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:30",
                    "end_time": "07:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Tuesday": [
        {
            "morning": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "07:30"
                }
            ],
            "afternoon": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:00",
                    "end_time": "05:00"
                }
            ],
            "evening": [
                {
                    "start_time": "02:30",
                    "end_time": "07:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}


for (var day in this.jsonData) {
  console.log("Day:" + day);
  
  // Accessing the array of schedules for the current day
  var schedules = this.jsonData[day];
  
  // Looping through the array of schedules
  for (var i = 0; i < schedules.length; i++) {
    var schedule = schedules[i];
    
    // Looping through the keys (morning, afternoon, evening)
    for (var timeOfDay in schedule) {
      console.log("Time of day: " + timeOfDay);
      
      // Accessing the array of time slots for the current time of day
      var timeSlots = schedule[timeOfDay];
      
      // Looping through the array of time slots
      for (var j = 0; j < timeSlots.length; j++) {
        var timeSlot = timeSlots[j];
        
        console.log("Start time: " + timeSlot.start_time);
        console.log("End time: " + timeSlot.end_time);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ps: Instead of logging everything, you can add a search key, and find a particular day or time, and you can also save those values somewhere too.